# recursion parameter issue

Tags: java, integer-division

```
public void mystery1(int n) {
if (n <= 1) {
    System.out.print(n);
} else {
    mystery1(n / 2);
    System.out.print(", " + n);
}
}
```

What gives this code for odd numbers. Becuase when we divide it it will not be an integer.

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Answer (score 1):

There is not mystery, because result of the integer division in Java is integer.

Answer (score 1):

In Java or most other programming languages, when you divide an integer by an integer, the result will be an integer. If a decimal number occurs, say for example:

```
5/2=2.5
```

then, the number before the decimal point will be treated as the integer and 2 will be chosen.

In case you want to explicitly convert the integer into float or double, you can use any of the following conversions:

```
(float) 3/2;

(double) n/2;
```

The above explicitly converts it to a decimal.

Comment: @LouisWasserman: I have mentioned that it takes the floor function of the number. So the floor of (-1/2) would be 0.

Comment: Traditionally, [no,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#Examples) that's not what "floor" means, even [as used in Java itself](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#FLOOR).

Answer (score 0):

`n / 2`, this is an integer division, where the fraction part will be ignored.

```
System.out.println(3/2); // prints 1
System.out.println(3.0/2); // prints 1.5
System.out.println(3/2.0); // prints 1.5
System.out.println(3.0/2.0); // prints 1.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Param will rounded to int, for example if param will be 5, the next call the function will be with param 2